# Adding layers of priority with sorting in C | qsort()

Tags: c, string, sorting, qsort

I'm trying to solve this codewars [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/strings-mix/train/c)

This is the jist of it

> Given two strings s1 and s2, we want to visualize how different the
>   two strings are. We will only take into account the lowercase letters
>   (a to z). First let us count the frequency of each lowercase letters
>   in s1 and s2.
>
> s1 = "A aaaa bb c"
>
> s2 = "& aaa bbb c d"
>
> s1 has 4 'a', 2 'b', 1 'c'
>
> s2 has 3 'a', 3 'b', 1 'c', 1 'd'
>
> So the maximum for 'a' in s1 and s2 is 4 from s1; the maximum for 'b'
>   is 3 from s2. In the following we will not consider letters when the
>   maximum of their occurrences is less than or equal to 1.

---

```
s1 = "my&friend&Paul has heavy hats! &"
s2 = "my friend John has many many friends &"
mix(s1, s2) --> "2:nnnnn/1:aaaa/1:hhh/2:mmm/2:yyy/2:dd/2:ff/2:ii/2:rr/=:ee/=:ss"
```

---

This is what I've come up with so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_letters(const void* a, const void* b){
    const char **ia = (const char **) a;
    const char **ib = (const char **) b;

    const char *sa = *ia;
    const char *sb = *ib;

    return (sa[2] < sb[2]) - (sa[2] > sb[2]);
}

char* mix(char* s1, char* s2){
    int i, j;
    char s1_rf[strlen(s1)];
    char s2_rf[strlen(s2)];
    int s1_n[26] = {0}, s2_n[26] = {0};

    i = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < strlen(s1); x++){
        if('a' <= s1[x] && s1[x] <= 'z'){
            s1_rf[i] = s1[x];
            s1_n[s1_rf[i] - 'a']++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < strlen(s2); x++){
        if('a' <= s2[x] && s2[x] <= 'z'){
            s2_rf[i] = s2[x];
            s2_n[s2_rf[i] - 'a']++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    char* combined_string[26];

    int size_s = 0;
    for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
        if(s1_n[ch - 'a'] != s2_n[ch - 'a']) {
            if (s1_n[ch - 'a'] > 1) {
                combined_string[size_s] = malloc(sizeof("3D4"));
                sprintf(combined_string[size_s], "1:%d%c", s1_n[ch - 'a'], ch);
                size_s++;
            }

            if (s2_n[ch - 'a'] > 1) {
                combined_string[size_s] = malloc(sizeof("3D4"));
                sprintf(combined_string[size_s], "2:%d%c", s2_n[ch - 'a'], ch);
                size_s++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (s2_n[ch - 'a'] > 1) {
                combined_string[size_s] = malloc(sizeof("3D4"));
                sprintf(combined_string[size_s], "=:%d%c", s2_n[ch - 'a'], ch);
                size_s++;
            }

        }
    }

    qsort(combined_string, (size_t) size_s, sizeof(combined_string[0]), compare_letters);

    char *final_string[size_s];

    j = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < size_s; x++){
        final_string[j] = malloc(sizeof(combined_string[x]));

        if(combined_string[x][3] == combined_string[x - 1][3]){
        }
        else{
            final_string[j] = combined_string[x];
            j++;
        }
    }

    char *return_string = malloc(sizeof("2:5D"));

    int k = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < j; x++){
        return_string[k] = final_string[x][0];
        k++;
        return_string[k] = final_string[x][1];
        k++;
        for(int y = 0; y < (final_string[x][2] - '0'); y++){
            return_string[k] = final_string[x][3];
            k++;

        }
        return_string[k] = '/';
        k++;
    }

    char *final_sting = malloc(sizeof(return_string));

    strncpy(final_sting, return_string, (size_t) (k - 1));

    puts(final_sting);

}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char s1[] = "Are they here";
    char s2[] = "yes, they are here";

    mix(s1, s2);
}
```

---

Console output

```
2:eeeee/=:hh/=:rr/2:yy
```

---

Expected output

```
2:eeeee/2:yy/=:hh/=:rr
```

As you can see, my way of count (of letters) sort doesn't take into account the string numbers.

So I was wondering if there's a way I could use my existing qsort() call or add another function which can add another layer of prioratization, first would be my letter count and if there are two or more equal counts, it'd sort according to the string number, and if there still are some unsorted, finally sort it alphabetically.

Comment: You might be interested in learning about [the standard character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: `malloc(sizeof("3D4"));` looks wrong - sure that is what you want?

Comment: @4386427 oh no that's just some experimental hard codding I did for debugging purposes. I'll be using a size_t variable from previous loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached this solution to your problem using a linked list and the sorting criteria you required for the insertion (number of appearances, sentence number, alphabetical order). Although not very efficient, it seems to be working pretty fine. Sorry I'm not following the steps of your solution, neither really answering to your question about *qsort*, but maybe you can make some use of the code below. (You should compile it with the flag *-std=c11*.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list
{
    int sentence;
    int repeats;
    char character;
    struct list * next;
} * List;

List insertSorted(List l, int s, int n, char c)
{
    List currentNode = l;
    List previousNode = NULL;
    while(currentNode && (currentNode->repeats > n || (currentNode->repeats == n && currentNode->sentence <= s)))
    {
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    List newNode = (List) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    newNode->sentence = s;
    newNode->repeats = n;
    newNode->character = c;
    newNode->next = currentNode;
    if(previousNode) previousNode->next = newNode;
    if(!l || l->repeats < n || (l->repeats == n && l->sentence > s)) l = newNode;
    return l;
}

char * mix(char * s1, char * s2)
{
    char alphasInS1[26];
    char alphasInS2[26];

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) alphasInS1[i] = alphasInS2[i] = 0;

    int n = 0;
    while(s1[n])
    {
        char c = s1[n];
        if(isalpha(c))
        {
            if(isupper(c)) c = (char) tolower(c);       
            int alphaIndex = ((int) c) - 97;
            ++(alphasInS1[alphaIndex]);
        }
        ++n;
    }

    n = 0;
    while(s2[n])
    {
        char c = s2[n];
        if(isalpha(c))
        {
            if(isupper(c)) c = (char) tolower(c);       
            int alphaIndex = ((int) c) - 97;
            ++(alphasInS2[alphaIndex]);
        }
        ++n;
    }

    int resultSize = 0;
    List alphaList = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if(alphasInS1[i] > 1 || alphasInS2[i] > 1)
        {
            if(alphasInS1[i] > alphasInS2[i])
            {
                resultSize += alphasInS1[i] + 3;
                alphaList = insertSorted(alphaList, 1, alphasInS1[i], (char) (97 + i));
            }
            else if(alphasInS1[i] < alphasInS2[i])
            {
                resultSize += alphasInS2[i] + 3;
                alphaList = insertSorted(alphaList, 2, alphasInS2[i], (char) (97 + i));
            }
            else if (alphasInS1[i] == alphasInS2[i])
            {
                resultSize += alphasInS1[i] + 3;
                alphaList = insertSorted(alphaList, 3, alphasInS1[i], (char) (97 + i));
            }
        }
    }

    if(!alphaList) return (char *) NULL;

    char * result = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (long unsigned) resultSize);

    n = 0;
    do
    {
        result[n++] = alphaList->sentence == 1 ? '1' : alphaList->sentence == 2 ? '2' : '=';
        result[n++] = ':';
        for(int i = 0; i < alphaList->repeats; ++i) result[n++] = alphaList->character;
        result[n++] = '/';
    }
    while((alphaList = alphaList->next));

    result[n - 1] = '\0';

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char s1[128], s2[128];

    strcpy(s1, "Are they here");
    strcpy(s2, "yes, they are here");

    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", mix(s1, s2));

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2:eeeee/2:yy/=:hh/=:rr
```